# Unknown extension tag found: Eclipse Plugin Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I’m customizing the Eclipse popup menu.
I’m not able to run my plugin code in debug mode. When I right click on **plugin project -> debug as -> Eclipse Application** the eclipse client is launched. But when I want to check my changes its not reflected and I get  Error in Console as:

> **!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-07-22 17:47:13.902
>   !MESSAGE Plugin zsample.menuitem, extension org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus, id zsample.menuitem.popup.actions.NewAction: Unknown extension tag found: actionProvider**

My Plugin.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
     <actionProvider
                class="zsample.menuitem.popup.actions.NewAction"
                id="zsample.menuitem.popup.actions.NewAction"
                overrides="com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.actions.AttributeValueSetDropDownAction"
                priority="highest">
            <enablement>
            <!-- A hack to allways be enabled -->
                <not>
                    <systemTest
                            property="MyApp"
                            value="WONT-EVER-BE-SET">
                    </systemTest>
                </not>
            </enablement>
        </actionProvider>
      </extension>
     </plugin>
```

I'm not sure why my NewAction.java doesn't go in debug mode. And why I'm getting  **Unknown extension tag found:**

Thanks,
Munna

Answer (score 1):

As error clearly says, `actionProvider` is not a valid element for `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`. Valid elements are `objectContribution` and `viewerContribution`.

Also note that `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is deprecated, in future versions it maybe removed. More information about popupMenus can be found [here.](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html&resultof=%22org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus%22%20)

Comment: You are right. I have made that changes and also when again try to launch the plugin with debug mode -> I don't see any effect of my plugin or even my code doesn't goes in debug mode. Please can you tell me why that link of this plugin is not happening or what is missing.